# Getting PID of shell script using $! does not give the correct (final) PID

Tags: bash, shell-script, process

I'm trying to get the PID of a shell script so I can kill it at a later date.

```
bash "home/lewis/builds/arduino/arduino-1.8.12/arduino" & disown
echo "$!"
```

The above runs and returns 37977

BUT

when I run `kill 37977` I get

```
bash: kill: (37977) - No such process
```

I assume this is because the script `/home/lewis/builds/arduino/arduino-1.8.12/arduino` then spawns other processes which are not 37977.

Is there a way I can get hold of the final PID of a shell script or any other command I run, usually it works a charm but this instance is causing me an issue.

I need a solution that's transferable to other commands in case this happens again.

Comment: Does `kill -37977` work?

Comment: bash: kill: 37977: invalid signal specification

Comment: Unfortunately there is no longer a 37977 pid running according to htop

Comment: Sorry, that should have been `kill -TERM -37977`. I am thinking that if you are right and 37977 is the PID of the arduino process which then launches other processes, then those other processes should all be in the same process _group_, whose PGID should be `37977`. If I'm right, `kill -TERM -37977` should kill all processes in that process group. Also check the output of `ps aux | grep 37977` (before killing anything) to see what's going on. Does it return anything?

Comment: Thanks for this, Its worked. But I've got another issue now. Is there a way to list out all the processes in that PGID? Or all the names? Realistically I need a list of all the new PID's spawned from the initial PID. You've been really helpful by the way you solved my other question!! :) Thanks

Comment: `ps axo pgrp,pid,cmd | grep "^ 37977 "` will list the processes in the process group 37977.

Comment: @LewisMorris I give you a way (essentially what icarus said) in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the spawned process is launching other processes and then exiting, the new processes should all have the same process group ID (PGID) and that should be the PID of the original process (37977 in your example). So what you want is a way of killing all processes in a PGID. This can be done with `kill` and a negative PID, as explained in `man kill`:

```
          -n     where n is larger than 1.  All processes in process group
                 n are signaled.  When an argument of  the  form  '-n'  is
                 given,  and it is meant to denote a process group, either
                 a signal must be specified first, or the argument must be
                 preceded  by a '--' option, otherwise it will be taken as
                 the signal to send.
```

So, what you're after is:

```
bash "home/lewis/builds/arduino/arduino-1.8.12/arduino" & disown
kill -TERM -"$!"
```

---

If what you need is to collect the list of individual PIDs, you can do:

```
bash "home/lewis/builds/arduino/arduino-1.8.12/arduino" & disown
ps -eo pgid,pid | awk -v pid=$! '$1==pid{print $2}')
```

That will return the list of PIDs whose PGID is `$!`. If your shell supports arrays (bash does), you could even do:

```
pids=($(ps -eo pgid,pid | awk -v pid=$! '$1==pid{print $2}'))
for pid in "${pids[@]}"; do echo "Killing $pid"; kill $pid; done
```

Or anything else you need.

Comment: One day, I hope I have the knowledge of Linux you do. Looking back now, I wish I had ditched windows years ago. So many years wasted. Every few years I would install a distribution only to go back to windows after a few days. But I'm about 6 months in and I don't see myself ever going back now. There is so much to learn, but I am getting there slowly. I appreciate your thorough answer.

Comment: @LewisMorris you're very welcome. As for learning, just hang out here! Nothing has taught me more about *nix than the time I've spent answering questions or reading answers here!